# Tracking Multiple Domains with Google Analytics in same code

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, multiple-domains

I have portal which behaves like multiple portal. 
The portal code base is same but for all sites but content is based on which url or domain you came across.
Currently i am able to track my domain

> example.com

and also subdomains like

> a.example.com, b.example.com

. But i want to also track

> anotherexample.com

which also point to same domain. How can I do?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#multipleDomains ?

Comment: anotherexample.com respond the same thing? Ir is it just a redirection?

Comment: it is not a redirection. as i said our portal behave like multiple portals. if you type abc.com you see abc site. if you type def.com you see def.com. Content is different? Make it clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiple url pointed to same code base. It does not matter. The only matter is the url above and the tracking code in site is matching or not. So you have to take google access code from database which just write in address bar.

Codes:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var accountNameFromDB = ...Some Operations...
    var domainNameFromDB = ...Some Operations...
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', accountNameFromDB]);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', domainNameFromDB]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
```

Just take accountNameFromDB and domainNameFromDB variables dynmically.
Add this code head of master page(or main template) or add every page.

Comment: I'm currently doing this, and it's completely incorrect and contrary to Google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains

Comment: this is prepared with this guide cerin. the difference is domainname and domain name unique id come from database.